# Element with border-radius shows artifacts after transition in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I have an element with `border-radius` applied that appears to leave a sort of trail (visual bug) behind when returning to its normal width after being shrunk to accommodate other enlarged elements. This seems to only happen when the `border-radius` property is used and the glitch level is proportional to the value of `border-radius`.

Basically, there are two elements inside a container with `display: flex`. The second element increases in width on hover and so the other element needs to shrink in order to not overflow. When I stop hovering, on the second element, the first one returns to its normal width, but it leaves a strange visual trail of its edge (pun unintended).

Before hover:

[image: before]

During hover:

[image: during]

After hover (the bug):

[image: after]

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#reduce {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

#hoverexpand {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  width: 20%;
}

#hoverexpand:hover {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="reduce">
  </div>
  <div id="hoverexpand">
    <span>Hover this</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Again, this only happens on Microsoft Edge and I'm baffled as to what might be causing it. Is this a known bug? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Could you try to add CSS prefixes to see if it solves the problem? Just paste your CSS there and replace it https://autoprefixer.github.io/

Comment: @Azametzin I just tried that, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. Well, no success here to solve this weird behavior. `Flexbox` is known to be buggy on Edge/IE. I would simply avoid to do some things, since there are cases with no solution. For example, `justify-content: space-evenly` doesnt work in Edge, so to mantain compatibility I simply don't use it. Good luck.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I'm not sure you understood the problem. This happens when the "Hover this" element gets hovered and expands, **not** when you hover over the grey element. Furthermore, Chrome doesn't do this, only Edge.

Comment: Yes, I misunderstand it. I check it again and I find that I can produce this issue with MS Edge. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue to Edge developers. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround. You can force Edge to repaint the affected element by promoting it to a composite layer with [`translateZ`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateZ).

You only have to set the following rule to your `#reduce` element:

```
transform: translateZ(0);
```

Here is the working example:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#reduce {
  flex: 2 0;
  background: #eee;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

#hoverexpand {
  flex: 1 0;
  transition: flex 0.5s ease;
}

#hoverexpand:hover {
  flex: 2 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="reduce">
  </div>
  <div id="hoverexpand">
    <span>Hover this</span>
  </div>
</div>
```